# App android en cuentas movil

Tags: android-studio

Como se puede añadir mi app en cuentas del móvil para que me haga un auto login al abrirla, sin necesidad de estar poniendo credenciales. 
Yo voy al apartado del móvil en cuentas y le doy añadir cuenta, s que salga mi app y le añada una cuenta.

Las app como Facebook o Whatsapp usan este procedimiento, tu puedes "cerrar" la app que cuando le des esta se abre, ya que tiene añadido en el apartado de cuentas tu cuenta de correo y contraseña. Yo quiero que mi app haga esto que se le añada una cuenta sea cual sea y que después me mantenga la sesión abierta.

He investigado algo pero no sé si voy bien encaminado y tampoco me aclaro:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorActivity
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager

Comment: Hola Pedro, no está muy claro lo que pides. Puedes aclararlo explicando lo que has investigado , el codigo que has intentado y un ejemplo de tu situacion actual y de la esperada?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Editado, codigo no he intendado porque no me aclaro nada, solo mi app te pide con que cuenta quieres logearte y quiero que no pida la cuenta, osea que la guarde como predeterminada. Abres la app y que diga vale tengo esta cuenta asignada en las cuentas del movil.